# How to repeat pattern in Processing

Tags: processing

I have the following code. I am trying to use TRANSLATE to move down the Y position on each loop pass, but it doesn't honor the Y position as indicated in the variable. Suggestions?

```java
int vShapePosX = 0;
int vShapePosY = 0;

int[] myVertX = { ... };
int[] myVertY = { ... };

void draw() {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 10) {
        fDrawRow();
        translate(vShapePosX, vShapePosY);
        vShapePosY = vShapePosY + 100;
        println(j);
        j = j + 1;
    }
    stop();
}
        
void fDrawRow(){
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 24) {
        // -------------- START -- DRAW SHAPE
        beginShape();
        int vCount = 0;
        while (vCount < 24) {
            vertex(myVertX[vCount], myVertY[vCount]);
            myVertX[vCount] = myVertX[vCount] + 85;     
            vCount++;                                   
        }
        endShape();
        // -------------- END -- DRAW SHAPE
        i = i + 1;
    } // end WHILE loop
} // end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) does not set a translation matrix. It constructs a new translation matrix and and multiplies the current matrix by the new matrix. Thus you have to save the current matrix by   [`pushMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html) before you apply the translation and you have to restore the matrix by [`popMatrix()`](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html) after drawing the object.
Furthermore, I suggest to use a [`for`](https://processing.org/reference/for.html)-loop and to reset the variable `vShapePosY` before the loop:

```java
void draw() {
    
    vShapePosY = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

        pushMatrix(); // <--- save current matrix

        translate(vShapePosX, vShapePosY); // <--- change current matrix 
        fDrawRow();

        popMatrix(); // <--- restore current matrix 
        
        vShapePosY = vShapePosY + 100;
    }
    stop();
}
```

---

Another approach is to gradually change the translation by (0, 100) in the loop:

```java
void draw() {

    translate(vShapePosX, vShapePosY);

    pushMatrix();
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
        fDrawRow();
        translate(0, 100); // <--- change current matrix 
    }
    popMatrix();

    stop();
}
```